# How to set auto increment field value in ORACLE bulk xml insert by using DBMS_XMLSave

Tags: xml, oracle, bulk

I am inserting bulk xml in oracle by using DBMS_XMLSave.  I am getting following exception ORA-20001: 43 ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: oracle.xml.sql.OracleXMLSQLException: 'java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ORA11G_41_DEVUPD"."LGEX"."REC_IDENTITY").

My table is

```
create table LGEX (
LOGDATE         DATE            NULL,
LOGLEN          numeric (10,0)  NULL,
LOGTIME         char(8)     NULL,
WORKSTATION     char(32)    NULL,
NETID           char(32)    NULL,
LOGHDR          char(10)    NULL,
BR              char(2)     NULL,
BRPROCDATE      DATE        NULL,
PCID            char(6)     NULL,
USERID          char(4)     NULL,
TASK            CHAR(20)        NULL,
EVENT           varchar2(100)   NULL,
LOGMESSAGE      NCLOB       NULL,
REC_IDENTITY        NUMERIC (15, 0) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT LGEXPK PRIMARY KEY (REC_IDENTITY))
/
CREATE SEQUENCE LGEX_REC_IDENTITY_SEQ INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 2
/
```

And SP i wrote is

```
create or replace procedure SP_ADDREC_LOG_OUTPUT_BULK(XMLSTRING IN clob) is
  insCtx DBMS_XMLSave.ctxType;
  doc clob;
  rows number;     
  SQL_DELQUERY VARCHAR2(4000);
  SQL_UPDATEQUERY VARCHAR2(4000); 
  C_DELIM CHAR(1) DEFAULT CHR(28);
    E_ERROROCCURRED EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(E_ERROROCCURRED, -20001);
begin   
        insCtx := DBMS_XMLSave.newContext('LOG_OUTPUT'); -- get the save context..!
         DBMS_XMLSave.setRowTag(insctx,'LogEntry');

         DBMS_XMLSave.setDateFormat(insctx,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS');
         DBMS_XMLSave.clearUpdateColumnList(insCtx); -- clear the update settings

         -- set the columns to be updated as a list of values..
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdateColumn(insCtx,'USERNAME'); 
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdateColumn(insCtx,'LOG_DATE');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'CATEGORY');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'TRANSACTION_STREAM');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'FUNCTION_CODE');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'SYSTEM_NAME');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'MESSAGE');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'MESSAGE_TYPE');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'SESSION_ID');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'THREAD_ID');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'SR_ID');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'TRACE_TOKEN');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'OWNER');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'APP_SRV_NAME');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'APP_SRV_IP');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'BR');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'SEQUENCE_NUMBER');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'SEQUENCE_LEVEL');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'TRANSACTION_ID');
         DBMS_XMLSave.setUpdatecolumn(insCtx,'LSTMNTDATE_DEF_TIME');

         -- Now insert the doc. 
         rows := DBMS_XMLSave.insertXML(insCtx, xmlString); 
         DBMS_XMLSave.closeContext(insCtx);               

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN E_ERROROCCURRED THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(SQLCODE, SQLERRM);
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, '43' || C_DELIM || RTRIM(SQLERRM) || C_DELIM || RTRIM(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK));
end;
/


I am looking for fast solution.
```

Comment: Which Oracle version?

Comment: What is the format of the XML?

Comment: Oracle 11G.  XML format is below.  Split and added as 2 comments

Comment: <LogEntries><LogEntry>
            <CATEGORY>MessageIn</CATEGORY>
            <FUNCTION_CODE></FUNCTION_CODE>
            <SYSTEM_NAME>SYBASE30D1</SYSTEM_NAME>
            <TRANSACTION_STREAM>OPERBROWSE</TRANSACTION_STREAM>
            <MESSAGE>My Message</MESSAGE>
            <LOG_DATE>4/22/2015 4:37:29 PM</LOG_DATE>
            <MESSAGE_TYPE>Unspecified</MESSAGE_TYPE>
            <SESSION_ID></SESSION_ID>

Comment: <USERNAME>SYS1</USERNAME>
            <THREAD_ID></THREAD_ID>
            <SR_ID></SR_ID>
            <OWNER>*</OWNER>
            <APP_SRV_NAME>BLRDEV118</APP_SRV_NAME>
            <APP_SRV_IP></APP_SRV_IP>
            <BR>01</BR>
            <SEQUENCE_NUMBER>0</SEQUENCE_NUMBER>
            <SEQUENCE_LEVEL>0</SEQUENCE_LEVEL>
            <TRANSACTION_ID>0</TRANSACTION_ID>  
            <TRACE_TOKEN></TRACE_TOKEN>  
            <LSTMNTDATE_DEF_TIME>4/22/2015 4:37:31 PM</LSTMNTDATE_DEF_TIME> 
            </LogEntry>    
</LogEntries>